# He collects stamps as a hobby

Tags: grammaticality

I'd like to know whether that sentence is grammatically correct.

To my way of thinking, that doesn't sound quite correct. If I were the writer who wrote that sentence, I would say as "Collecting stamps is one of his hobbies"

But If we could think of "a hobby" as modifying the whole sentence "he collects stamps", I'd think that that sentence could be grammatically acceptable.

I'd like to know your opinions on my thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "He collects stamps as a hobby" is grammatically correct.  So is, "Collecting stamps is one of his hobbies." You could also say, "He has a hobby of collecting stamps," or, "He is a stamp collector."

In the sentence, "He collects stamps as a hobby," you can break it down like this:

- "He collects stamps"
- How does he collect stamps? "as a hobby"

Comment: And do you agree that "a hobby" is modifying the whole sentence "He collects stamps"? I'm a little confused over the use of "as" in this way because it's my first time that I've seen it used like this.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to bring out some sentences similar to that sentence as well?

Comment: He eats babies as an amusement; he sells used cars as a business.

Comment: @Michael Harvey To me, "an amusement" and "a busniess" are actually modifying its preceding sentence.

Comment: Of course they are.